# Realtek rtl8723de wifi not working with a new kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 20.04, realtek

I was using linux kernel 5.0.4-33 generic and 5.0.4-31-generic.

But after some time i needed to reinstall the 5.0.4-33-generic kernel because it was giving me initramfs error during boot.
After reinstalling the kernel boots perfectly without errors but the there is no wifi option there while wifi works perfectly for 5.0.4-31-generic kernel.

I am using Realtek8723de driver.

i tried following these instructions

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307

but the latest commit of Larry Finger's rtlwifi_new repo says

"if you are running a kernel newer than 5.0, use the drivers built into your kernel."

But this is not the case it seems. There is still no option for wifi

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

I really need this to work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Larry Finger has made a new repo for these drivers.

You can install drivers this way now:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

But you may have problems with previously installed drivers.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who need Realtek 8723DE support. You need at least Linux kernel 5.8 and additional firmware rtw8723d_fw.bin from linux-firmware package. Search for enabled CONFIG_RTW88_8723DE in kernel config. Info: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RTW88_8723DE.html

Answer (score -1):

After a while i found out that linux tools was not installed

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-5.4.0-33 linux-tools-5.4.0-33-generic
```

This command worked for me

Comment: This is completely unrelated. Do you have an rtl8723de device?

Comment: Yes, i do have rtl8722de. I removed the kernel using synaptic. Then removed remaining files using ```sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic``` then updated the grub menu. This removed the kernel completely. Then i installed the kernel again using synaptic which installed the kernel and i was able to boot into that kernel perfectly fine. But synaptic didn't installed linux-tools. For that kernel which included the drivers for wifi.

Comment: `linux-tools` doesn't contain drivers.