# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu on HP Laptop - 15-di2000tu

Tags: wireless, 20.04, bluetooth

I have HP Laptop - 15-di2000tu and both WiFi and Bluetooth were working on Windows. After installing Ubuntu 20.04 WiFi is working fine but Bluetooth is showing error "No Bluetooth found. Plugin a dongle to use Bluetooth".

Network Adapter is `RTL8723DE`

`rfkill list` output

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`bluetoothctl` output is `Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...`

`lspci` output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bca (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b1 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation BG3 NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
```

`lsusb` output

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56c9 IMC Networks HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`uname -r` output is `5.8.0-55-generic`

`hcitool dev` output is empty `Devices:`

`sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

Other outputs:

```
USER@USER:~$ apt list --installed bluetooth* blueman* bluez*
Listing... Done
bluez-cups/now 5.53-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.53-0ubuntu3.3]
bluez-obexd/now 5.53-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.53-0ubuntu3.3]
bluez/now 5.53-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.53-0ubuntu3.3]
USER@USER:~$ lsmod | grep -i blue
bluetooth             581632  0
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
USER@USER:~$ dmesg -T | grep -i blue
[Thu Jul 15 11:03:03 2021] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[Thu Jul 15 11:03:03 2021] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[Thu Jul 15 11:03:03 2021] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[Thu Jul 15 11:03:03 2021] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[Thu Jul 15 11:03:03 2021] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
USER@USER:~$ bluetooth

Command 'bluetooth' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install tlp

USER@USER:~$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*' | grep 8723
/lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8723bs/r8723bs.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_8723d.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_8723de.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.ko
USER@USER:~$ grep 8723 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias
alias pci:v000010ECd00008723sv*sd*bc*sc*i* rtl8723ae
alias pci:v000010ECd0000B723sv*sd*bc*sc*i* rtl8723be
alias pci:v000010ECd0000D723sv*sd*bc*sc*i* rtw88_8723de
alias sdio:c*v024CdB723* r8723bs
alias sdio:c*v024Cd0627* r8723bs
alias sdio:c*v024Cd0626* r8723bs
alias sdio:c*v024Cd0623* r8723bs
alias sdio:c*v024Cd0525* r8723bs
alias sdio:c*v024Cd0523* r8723bs
alias acpi*:OBDA8723:* hci_uart
alias of:N*T*Crealtek,rtl8723bs-btC* hci_uart
alias of:N*T*Crealtek,rtl8723bs-bt hci_uart
USER@USER:~$ grep 8723 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/btcoexist/btcoexist.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko kernel/lib/crypto/libarc4.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/btcoexist/btcoexist.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko kernel/lib/crypto/libarc4.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko kernel/lib/crypto/libarc4.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_8723d.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_core.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko kernel/lib/crypto/libarc4.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_8723de.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_8723d.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_pci.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88_core.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko kernel/lib/crypto/libarc4.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8723bs/r8723bs.ko: kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue, please update if you got the answer

Comment: Can you add the output of ```lspci``` and ```lsusb```?. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlesMateo updated, please check.

Comment: Please add the output of `uname -r` as well.

Comment: @KamalPaliwal what is the output of ```hcitool dev``` ?. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Panda output updated, please check.

Comment: @CarlesMateo output updated, please check.

Comment: Thanks @KamalPaliwal the RTL8723DE is a combo Wifi + bluetooth and support for it was added to Kernels 4.17 or newer. Check that your laptop has not it disabled by keyboard combination. I found two pages that explain how to install the driver, however your kernel should support it natively: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307 and https://superuser.com/questions/1301390/bluetooth-not-working-for-realtek-rtl8723de-hci0-didnt-find-patch-for-chip-i/1322067#1322067

Comment: Also please check if you have this file ```/etc/bluetooth/main.conf``` and make sure it has ```AutoEnable=true``` so bluetooth is started when you start your computer.

Comment: Also check if service is started ```sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service```.
Cheers

Comment: Your kernel natively should support. Check the 2nd given answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247915/realtek-rtl8723de-wifi-not-working-with-a-new-kernel/1347347#1347347). The [link](https://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/sources/linux-firmware/rtw88/) for the bin file. Run this to see your kernel config: `less /boot/config-$(uname -r)`.

Comment: @CarlesMateo yes as I have Kernel > 4.17 so it has support for RTL8723DE and I have also tried the solution in the link that you shared, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Mr.Panda it shows ```Linux/x86 5.8.0-55-generic Kernel Configuration``` and ```CONFIG_RTW88_8723DE=m``` in the output of ```less /boot/config-$(uname -r)```. The binary file also exist at ```/lib/firmware/rtw88/rtw8723d_fw.bin```.

Comment: May I see the log as well? `journalctl -xg rtw`

Comment: What happens if you install the tlp package as it suggests and restart your Bluetooth service (basically this is the same as #3 from sancho.s's response)?

Comment: @Mr.Panda here is the response of ```journalctl -xg rtw``` https://prnt.sc/1bp6y2s.

Comment: Now it is more clear. Here are my suggestions. Start from the 1st one and try one by one. (i) Disabling Bluetooth in the BIOS, rebooting and enabling it in the BIOS again as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1310775/bluetooth-adapter-not-detected-on-linux). (ii) check if there any Bluetooth settings in the GUI that you can enable or disable. (iii) switch to another Linux OS than Ubuntu as use [Larry's driver.](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88). (iv) `rfkill unblock bluetooth`. (This is just in case if your Bluetooth is soft blocked after you do the 2nd step.)

Comment: @Mr.Panda (i) There is no option in the BIOS to disable bluetooth. (ii) It doesn't allow me to enable bluetooth from GUI and I have tried to switch to Airplane mode but nothing worked. (iii) I have tried Larry's driver in Ubuntu 18 and Mint also earlier but it gave me same issue that WiFi started working but bluetooth doesn't works. (iv) ```rfkill unblock bluetooth``` also does nothing as bluetooth is not showing in ```rfkill list```.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this would likely require back and forth interaction, with the following actions from your side:

1. Posting promptly the output of various diagnostic commands.
2. Checking the links that are provided.

This was already happening in comments.

---

Please post the output of

```
$ apt list --installed bluetooth* blueman* bluez*
$ lsmod | grep -i blue
$ dmesg -T | grep -i blue
$ bluetooth
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*' | grep 8723
$ grep 8723 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias
$ grep 8723 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep
```

Tentative solutions:

1. Disable Bluetooth in the BIOS, reboot and enable it in the BIOS again. See e.g., [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348005) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1451102/245595).
2. As per [this](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06515269), the (WiFi+Bluetooth) adapter is *Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n (1x1) and Bluetooth® 4.2 combo*.
   It may be the case that the driver for it is not available.
   To check this you could see the output of one [command above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184880/137608), or you could [try typing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229321/137608) `modprobe rtl8723` and then <tab> to see tab-completion options.
   If it is not available, you would have to install it. See e.g. [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/04/nstall-rtl8723de-wifi-driver-ubuntu-19-04/), [this](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/02/21/step-by-step-ubuntu-20-04-realtek-rtl8723de-driver-installation-guide/), or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247915/realtek-rtl8723de-wifi-not-working-with-a-new-kernel).
3. `sudo systemctl bluetooth.service start`

Comment: I have added the output of the command above, please check.

Comment: @KamalPaliwal - You did not post what happened after trying 1 and 3.

Comment: Seems there is no option for Bluetooth setting in BIOS options. For the point 3 output is ```Unknown operation bluetooth.service.```

Answer (score 0):

Checking Bluetooth Status

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

if it's not active then

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth

sudo systemctl bluetooth.service start
```

scanning

```
bluetoothctl scan on
```

To make your Bluetooth adapter discoverable to other devices,

```
bluetoothctl discoverable on
```

Connecting to Your Device

```
bluetoothctl pair FC:69:47:7C:9D:A3

bluetoothctl connect FC:69:47:7C:9D:A3
```

Listing Paired Devices With bluetoothctl

```
bluetoothctl paired-devices
```

Trusting Paired Devices

```
bluetoothctl trust FC:69:47:7C:9D:A3
```

Disconnecting Bluetooth Devices

```
bluetoothctl remove FC:69:47:7C:9D:A3

bluetoothctl disconnect FC:69:47:7C:9D:A3
```

Using the Interactive Mode

```
bluetoothctl
```

Comment: Bluetooth status is inactive and ```sudo systemctl bluetooth.service start``` output is ```Unknown operation bluetooth.service.```

Comment: I have the same issue on 20.10 but that;s another story. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware` then rebooting?